# Webpack Dev Build /sockjs-node/XXXXXXXXXXXX/xhr_streaming?t=XXXXXXXX is called many times

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

**My webpack config file for dev mode**
when i am starting node server in dev mode 
multiple requests(eg: http://localhost:8090/sockjs-node/563/14x42n5e/xhr_streaming?t=1578560165901) are hitting to the server 
this is happing on dev mode, not in prod build

I am guessing this is happening because of hot reload option

```
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const eslintFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter');
const LodashModuleReplacementPlugin = require('lodash-webpack-plugin');
const { ReactLoadablePlugin } = require('react-loadable/webpack');
const ErrorOverlayPlugin = require('error-overlay-webpack-plugin');
const DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');
const { getAppEnv } = require('./env');

const env = getAppEnv();
const { PUBLIC_URL = '' } = env.raw;
const resolvePath = relativePath => path.resolve(__dirname, relativePath);

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&reload=true',
    resolvePath('../src/index.js')
  ],
  output: {
    path: resolvePath('../build'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
    publicPath: PUBLIC_URL + '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: eslintFormatter
            },
            loader: 'eslint-loader'
          }
        ],
        include: resolvePath('../src')
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: resolvePath('../src'),
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'svg-url-loader',
            options: {
              // Inline files smaller than 10 kB
              limit: 10 * 1024,
              noquotes: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              // Inline files smaller than 10 kB
              limit: 10 * 1024
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              mozjpeg: {
                enabled: false
                // NOTE: mozjpeg is disabled as it causes errors in some Linux environments
                // Try enabling it in your environment by switching the config to:
                // enabled: true,
                // progressive: true,
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false
              },
              optipng: {
                optimizationLevel: 7
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: '65-90',
                speed: 4
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        exclude: [resolvePath('../src/styles')],
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              // camelCase: true,
              // modules: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'postcss',
              plugins: () => [
                require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                autoprefixer({
                  // browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'not ie < 11'],
                  flexbox: 'no-2009'
                })
              ]
            }
          },
          'sass-loader',
          'import-glob-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        include: [resolvePath('../src/styles')],
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'postcss',
              plugins: () => [
                require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                autoprefixer({
                  // browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'not ie < 11'],
                  flexbox: 'no-2009'
                })
              ]
            }
          },
          'sass-loader',
          'import-glob-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.forWebpackDefinePlugin),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new ErrorOverlayPlugin(),
    new DashboardPlugin(),
    new ReactLoadablePlugin({
      filename: 'build/react-loadable.json'
    })
  ],
  node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};
```

screenshots... 
[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably answered your own question.

Comment: @urbz I didn't know can you help me with the solution

Comment: Well, you probably don't have hot reload in production and since you have it in dev you could try turning it off and see the number of requests it makes. Also, check your code which initially requests the data from the server.